# Why can't I print to PDF in BlackBerry-10 with QTextDocument?

Tags: qt, pdf, blackberry-10

```
QTextDocument *td = new QTextDocument();
td->setHtml("<p>blah blah blah </p>");
QPrinter printer;
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter:: PdfFormat);
printer.setOrientation(QPrinter::Portrait);
printer.setPaperSize(QPrinter::Letter);
printer.setOutputFileName(filenamer);
td->print(&printer);
```

Permission to write files are good. QPrinter prints pdf from images in other code I have. But HTML in a QTextDocument doesn't work. Doesn anyone know why? I use Cascades as my GUI.

Comment: is output file address valid?

Comment: just works fine for me with no problem

Comment: Works fine for you in a BB10 app?

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code on version 10.2.1 simulator the call to `td->print(&printer)` results in the error message `QPainter::begin(): Returned false`.

I suspect that this is because Cascades, while derived from Qt is an extension of Qt so not all Qt facilities work. Font rendering to a QPainter is one of the things that doesn't work. This is probably the issue you have run into.